# SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} How to change to show only logged in users posts

Tags: wordpress, post

Im trying to make what seems like a simple adjustment to a plugin im using, unfortunately im just a 'wannabe programmer' and not the real deal so i wa shoping someone whom is a real programmer can help me out here. If you can help me i would be foreever grateful and even willing to pay a bit for someone to explain this process to me...... here goes:

Im working with a plugin, it has a list of posts recently created and shows ALL posts no matter which user i login with... I would like to change this to show ONLY post by the user whom is logged in... below is the file\

```
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $current_time = current_time('mysql') + 60;

    $ereminder_array = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM {$wpdb->posts}

    WHERE post_date <= %s

    AND post_type ='ereminder'
    AND post_status = 'draft'
    AND author = 'wp_current_user'
    ORDER BY post_date ASC
    ", $current_time) );
    $scheduled_data = array(
    'list' => $ereminder_array,
    'type' => 'scheduled'
    );
    echo PDER_Utils::get_view( 'ereminder-list.php', $scheduled_data );
     ?>
```

if anybody can tell me how to alter above code to show only post by the user that is logged in instead of all the users like it does now i would be forever grateful.

thanks in advance

Comment: the query you have already has a where clause to filter by author, does that not work?

Comment: are you referring to the line below?

AND author = 'wp_current_user'

If yes sorry my mistake, i actually added this line but i did not have an effect.

if you meant another line please let me know which? thaks for taking time out to help

Comment: please change post_status = publish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
global $wpdb;
$current_time = current_time('mysql') + 60;

$ereminder_array = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare("
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts

WHERE post_date <= %s

AND post_type ='ereminder'
AND post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = %d
ORDER BY post_date ASC
", $current_time, $current_user->ID) );
$scheduled_data = array(
'list' => $ereminder_array,
'type' => 'scheduled'
);
echo PDER_Utils::get_view( 'ereminder-list.php', $scheduled_data );
 ?>
```